# How to access an application using different host and port with JBoss 5

Tags: java, jboss5.x

I have deployed my application in Jboss and I want to give users access to my application with different host and ports per user. To explain clearly:

```
http://192.168.11.21/MBeanProject/servcount
```

for user1 and

```
http://192.168.11.22/MBeanProject/servcount
```

for user2 so on...

How could I do this?  I am using JBoss5 as my AS.  Based on the user request I need to count the number of times that user1 accessed the first url and the number of times the user2 accessed the second one ...and so on...  Can you guide me how could I procced? Currently I am working with the Snmp traps using JBoss5

Answer (score 1):

You will need a separate IP address for every user, right?  Which doesn't sound like a very scalable solution, but if you do decide to do this you will then need as many IP addresses as you have users, and tell JBoss to listen to all interfaces using a startup argument like `bin/run.sh -b 0.0.0.0`.  Then, your Servlets will be able to tell the full IP address by checking (eg) [HttpServletRequest#getRequestUrl()](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL%28%29).  Or, you could have a separate instance of JBoss running for each user, binding each one to a different IP.

However, this is a very unusual design.  It offers poor scalability, difficult maintenance, difficult network config and sysadmin tasks, and confusion for any new devs on the project.  Appservers are designed to be able to serve multiple users on the same instance.  I can't really see any positives to a design like this.  Unless you have very good reasons for doing so (in which case please share!) you should probably use different URLs for different users, like:

```
http://192.168.11.21/MBeanProject/user1/servcount
http://192.168.11.21/MBeanProject/user2/servcount
```

or

```
http://192.168.11.21/MBeanProject/servcount?user=user1
http://192.168.11.21/MBeanProject/servcount?user=user2
```

Comment: good and I will agree with that. But, what will be the user1 http://192.168.11.21/MBeanProject/user1/servcount appended to the url.  I developed a simple servlet and sent to different users, in the sense different people to access the link. say for ex http://192.168.11.21/MBeanProject/servcount I need to count the users requests. how could I append user1 to the url.Help me in that and how could I proceed

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but I guess you need to send different links to different users.

Comment: thanks dude...your approach is right.Also I need to check if the request is first time count will be 1 for user1 like..if for user2 the count will be 1 so we have total two counts 1 for user1 and 1 for user2. If the user2 requests the same url the user2 count should be 2 and user1 count will be 1. The same way we need to track. I am using JBoss5 snmp-adaptor.jar but the documentation is not clear for that. Help me in some more possibilities.